# Syntax error while trying to fetch data from MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

So I am trying to fetch a value from the database, selecting the row using WHERE INT.

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(DBdetails.connStr);
conn.Open();
query = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE table=@tafel";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tafel", tafel);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However it wont pass 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()', it throws a error saying the syntax isnt right like: "near table=1", "near table=2"

I tried fetching a other one in the same table that is a var char and it worked perfectly.

Don't really see what I am doing wrong. The 'table' column is a int and 'tafel' is a int to.

Thanks!

Comment: u have a column name as `table` ?

Comment: *table* is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) - try quoting it or changing the column name

Comment: As noted, you need to put `table` in backticks because it is a reserved word.  The list of reserved words is in the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html.  This is a very common MySQL question, and many people on the site think such questions should be closed as duplicates or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your field name `table` in backticks (`table` is a reserved word in *MySQL*) :

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM `tables` WHERE `table` = @tafel";
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.. knew it was something small but I always confuse with this shit. Will accept awnser in 10m!, is there also a awnser why this is needed?

Comment: @user2911924 : Yes, there is, as I've said above, table is a reserved word in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `table` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to use quote with it like

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE `table` = @tafel";
```

However, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` like;

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBdetails.connStr))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tables WHERE `table` = @tafel";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tafel", tafel);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

By the way, I don't understand why you use `ExecuteNonQuery` with `SELECT` statement. It just executes your query. It doesn't even return any value.

If you want to get the result of your query, you can use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as your result rows.